# Closure objects within arrays before PHP 5.3

Tags: php, anonymous-function, php-5.2

I know it's possible to do the following with PHP 5.3 (anonymous functions), but is there a similar alternative in older PHP version (pre-5.3)?

```
  $exampleArray = array(  
    'func' => function() {  
      echo 'this is an example';  
      }
```

Is it possible to do this with __call or typecasting the function as an (object) first?  Also, I tried making the function un-anonymous by giving it a name, but this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to create anonymous in PHP < 5.3, you can use
[`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) function.  Also [*Here*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) is interesting information about callbacks (may be usefull).

**Example using** `create_function`

```
# This (function in other variable is only for cleaner code)
$func = create_function('', "echo 'This is example from anoymus function';");

$exampleArray = array(
  'func' => $func
  );
```

But you can do the same thing liek code above with alternative way:

```
# Create some function
function func()
{
   # Do something
   echo 'This is example';
}
# Save function name
$func = 'func';
```

Code above creates function which does something, then we store function name in variable (can be passed as parameter, etc.).

Calling function when we know only it's name:

**First way**

```
$func();
```

**Alternative**

```
call_user_func($func);
```

So example that connects everything above:

```
function primitiveArrayStep(&$array, $function)
{
    # For loop, foreach can also be used here
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array);$i++)
    {
         # Check if $function is callable             
          if( is_callable($function) )
          {
               # Call function
           $function(&$array[$i]);
          }
          else
          {
               # If not, do something here
          }

    }    
}
```

And use of above function:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$myFunction = create_function('&$e', '$e = $e . " and i was here";');

primitiveArrayStep($array, $myFunction);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
```

Returns:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "a and i was here"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "b and i was here"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "c and i was here"
}
```

**Links:**

- [Callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.callbacks.php)
- [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)
- [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)
- [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible to create **lamda** functions with PHP pre 5.3 using [create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). It isn't possible to create **closures** though which your question mentions but doesn't actually use.

A *closure* is a lamda function that has access (closes over) a variable from it's enclosing scope:

```
$t = new Thingy;
$func = function( $y ) use( $t ) {
    //$t is available here when this function is called;
}
```

A *lamda* function is an anonymous function useful for storing in a variable or passing as an argument etc. You can use `create_function()` pre 5.3 like this:

```
$func = create_function( '$y', 'echo $y;' );

//similar to

$func = function( $y ){ echo $y };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$exampleArray = array(
    'func' => create_function('', 'echo "this is an example"');
);
```

[create_function](http://php.net/create_function)

Comment: Inspirational answer. I've learned so much. It feels like this answer deserves much more attention. Such PHP powers.

Answer (score 0):

What about just creating a class with 'func' as a class method?  Would work pre or post 5.3.