# How to add this function into an array

Tags: php, arrays, function

Is it possible to include this function

```
function Get_All_Wordpress_Menus(){
    return get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) ); 
}
```

into this array

```
array(
    'options' => ADD_FUNCTION_HERE,
);
```

Comment: Do you want to return value of the function in the array or the ACTUAL function in the array?

Comment: I want to return to value of the function (It's a select box that shows a list of menus that exist within a Wordpress based site, so I need to display that list with each menu as an select option). Sorry, PHP isn't really my forte

Comment: anonymous function ??

Comment: You could indeed use Anonymous Functions, check out Vladimir Hraban's answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need this ?

```
function Get_All_Wordpress_Menus(){
    return get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) ); 
}

$arr = array(
    'options' => Get_All_Wordpress_Menus(),
);
```

Comment: I think that he want to use this function somewhere else and trying to store it on `$arr` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the function in an array do this:
[Example](http://3v4l.org/NHnmN)

```
function foo($text = "Bar")
{
    echo $text;
}

// Pass the function to the array. Do not use () here.
$array = array(
    'func' => "foo" // Reference to function
);

// And call it.
$array['func'](); // Outputs: "Bar"
$array['func']("Foo Bar"); // Outputs: "Foo Bar"
```

If you need to pass the return value, it's very simple (assuming previous example):

```
$array['value'] = foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the function itself, use anonymous functions

```
$arr = array(
    'options' => function()
                {
                    return get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) );  
                }
);
```

You can then call it like

```
$func = $arr['options'];
$func();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Note that before PHP 5.3 it was not possible. Although there is a workaround that is described in [Closure objects within arrays before PHP 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850778/closure-objects-within-arrays-before-php-5-3)

Answer (score 0):

```
  function Get_All_Wordpress_Menus($call){


$call = get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) ); 
return $call;
 }


$array = array(
'options' => $call,
);
```

OR

```
 $array = array(
'options' => Get_All_Wordpress_Menus($call),
);
```